# Marble probability without replacement question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There is a bag of 15 marbles, 13 red and two blue. If you pick 9 marbles without replacement, what is the probability that:
>
> a) One blue marble is left in the bag
>
> b) Both blue marbles are still the bag
>
> c) No blue marbles are left in the bag

This was an intro to probability question that I can't crack. I'm not even sure where to start - intuition doesn't help much. How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 1):

$\underline{An\; alternative\;method}$

You can solve all the 3 problems by considering only the blue marbles.

There are 6 "in bag" slots and 9 "out of bag" slots.

P(one blue marble in bag) $=\dfrac{\binom61\binom91}{\binom{15}2}$

Answer (score 0):

You have a bag containing 13 red and 2 blue marbles, and on removing 9 marbles without replacement want to know the probabilities for counts of blue marbles in the bag.

This is the essentially same a taking a bag of 13 red and 2 blue marbles, and on removing 6 calculating the probabilities for counts of blue marbles removed.   That is, the count has a Hypergeometric distribution.

> a) One blue marble is left in the bag

Assuming this means "exactly" one, then it is the probability for leaving 1 from 2 blue marbles and 5 from 13 red marbles in the bag when leaving any 6 from the 15 marbles in the bag without bias or replacement of the 9 removed marbles.

$$\mathsf P(B=1)~=~ \dfrac{\dbinom 2 1\dbinom {13}5}{\dbinom{15}6}$$

The rest is left to you.